# Standard LiPo battery packs & product liability

Tags: safety, lipo, reliability

I'm designing a high-power portable product that I would like to eventually bring to market. I need to use LiPo battery packs in order to achieve sufficient energy density, but I do not think I will have the resources to navigate the regulatory hurdles associated with LiPo safety.

If I was using Alkaline batteries, for example, I would simply require the consumer to BYO batteries, and therefore not be exposed to the liability if those batteries explode in someone's face!

Lithium Polymer batteries seems to be much less standardised. Is it possible to obtain off-the-shelf standardised LiPo battery products that include internal charging and safety circuitry, where the battery manufacturer is the liable party in the event of a dangerous battery malfunction?

I am not asking for a list of recommendations, rather a confirmation that the approach I'm describing is a valid strategy for outsourcing battery risk.

I feel like this is a common concern in real-life Electrical Engineering and circuit design, so hopefully I'm not too far off-topic for this forum.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try calling battery manufacturers.  "Will you indemnify my company against accidents involving the batteries" would be the key phrase.

Comment: This might be better suited to the law SE?

Comment: Your brand reputation is still damaged if the battery the customer added catches fire or explodes.